# Showing something is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am working with this 
$h(p)=( \int _0 ^1|f(x)|^pdx)^{1/p}$

where $1 \leq p < \infty$ and I am trying to show h is increasing.

Attempt

$\operatorname{sng}(|f|)=1$
so $(\int_0 ^1 \operatorname{sng}(|f|)^q)^{1/q}=1$ thus we can consider

$$((\int_0 ^1 \operatorname{sng}(|f|)^q)^{1/q}= \int _0 ^1|f(x)|^p \, dx)^{1/p} \geq \int_0 ^1 |f(x) \operatorname{sqn}(f)|=\|f\|_1 $$

Basically using the holders inequality does this look good?

Answer (score 2):

Let $1 \leq p < q < \infty$.  The function $a(x):= x^{q/p}$ defined on non-negative reals is convex (it has non-negative second derivative).

By Jensen's inequality,

$$ \left( \int_0^1 |f|^p dx \right)^{q/p}= a \left( \int_0^1 |f|^p dx \right)  \leq \int_0^1 a(|f|^p)dx = \int_0^1 |f|^q dx.$$

Take $q$th roots to see that

$$h(p) \leq h(q)$$

as required.

Comment: Is this possible without Jensen's inequality because I have never learned and it is an oddity to me. Thanks your the response

Comment: It's a pleasure. It is well worth just learning Jensen's inequality (and it's proof, which is simple). It's very useful, and this is the way you will find this problem done in any book.

Comment: You make a good point, I think the intake here is to Learn a new tool. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use the Holder Inequality to prove:
$$\int_0^1|f(x)g(x)|dx\le\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^\alpha dx\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\left(\int_0^1|g(x)|^\beta dx\right)^{\frac{1}{\beta}}$$
where $\alpha,\beta>1$ satisfy $\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=1$.
For $p_1<p_2$, choose $\alpha=\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^{p_1}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p_1}}\\
&\le&\left[\left(\int_0^1(|f(x)|^{p_1})^\alpha dx\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\left(\int_0^11^\beta dx\right)^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\right]^{\frac{1}{p_1}}\\
&\le&\left[\int_0^1(|f(x)|^{p_1\alpha} dx\right]^{\frac{1}{\alpha p_1}}\\
&=&\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^{p_2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p_2}}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus $\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is increasing for $p>1$.